# How can I making a rectangular box around a text link?

Tags: html, css

Please let me know that how can I wrap a text link in a rectangular box with round corner and background color like this site:
http://tandorosti.akairan.com/health/vegetable-health/nargil.html

The blue boxes?

Answer (score 0):

In the CSS of the class or id of the link, use the following properties:

- `border-radius` This makes the edges rounded
- `background` This makes the color of the box

You may also want to have the border of same colour as background using `border-color` property